# rand() seed that does not involve time?

Tags: c++, random, time, srand

Using `srand(time(NULL))` seems overly deterministic. For example, when I run `std::cout << rand() % 9000` I get 4275. When I run it again, I get 4311. It's too based on time.

Comment: That was just by chance they were that close to each other. It happens when your number is random.

Comment: Also, since you asked for C++, you might want to consider using [the new random number library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: While your example is not sufficient evidence for a problem, I wouldn't use `rand`. If you use a PRNG that doesn't suck, it'll output completely different sequences even if the input is very similar. Even with perfect seeds, `rand` has horrible flaws, including the insufficient seed and state size.

Comment: @Csq it's amazing how many answers to that question don't attempt to answer the actual question. I think this one is specific enough to be considered different.

Comment: You think that is deterministic?  I challenge you to guess the next number.

Comment: @MarkRansom " it's amazing how many answers to that question don't attempt to answer the actual question" - yes. Even though I like the `srand((time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000))` in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MartinKonecny, it's not chance, I've run into the same problem myself with Microsoft's implementation of `rand`. The formula used shows a definite correlation between the seed and the first value produced.

Comment: For generating the high-entropy seed value itself, the proper thing to use is the [`std::random_device`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) class, as part of the new `<random>` library. For older compilers (pre-C++11), you can use [TR1 random library](http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html), or [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), which are nearly the same. Otherwise, you can also read from [`/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`](http://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random) or the non-Unix equivalent (?).

Answer (score 1):

If you use C++ I'd recommend using `<random>` from the standard library. It is much more reliable than `rand()`

Comment: +1 And if you're using an older compiler, `<random>` was added as part of TR1, so it's also available under `<tr1/random>` as `std::tr1::mt19937` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are just taking two samples, and assuming it is representative of the overall population (ie: statistical fallacy based on insignificant sample size). The `rand()` function returns values that effectively form a uniform distribution on `[0, RAND_MAX]`. The example you provided isn't a very good one.

Second, calling `srand(time(NULL))` is a decent approach in general on most modern machines. The only time where it poses a significant security risk is when running on a single-core embedded chip that doesn't have a battery backup for the system clock. I've worked with some Motorola boards that do this, and about 90% of the time, when our program loaded up, we ended up getting the same random seed value. I believe some Bingo machines in the 80's were vulnerable to this since they were designed to be left running 24/7, but the operators were shutting them down every night.

Finally, `rand()` is half-decent at best. If you want a random number generator that has better properties (ie: "close" seed values not providing a similar pattern, a wider range of output values, minimal bias), consider going with an external RNG algorithm.

**References**

---

1. *Recommended way to initialize srand?*, Accessed 2014-06-02, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322938/recommended-way-to-initialize-srand)
2. *What difference between rand() and random() functions?*, Accessed 2014-06-02, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726102/what-difference-between-rand-and-random-functions>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726102/what-difference-between-rand-and-random-functions)
3. *What alternatives are there to the C library's rand() and srand()?*, Accessed 2014-06-02, [`<http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/random.html>`](http://benpfaff.org/writings/clc/random.html)

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you're stuck using `rand()`, try draining a couple of values from it after calling `srand`. The correlation is greatest on the first call to `rand` and decreases from that point on.

```
  srand(time(NULL));
  rand();
  rand();
```

You can also seed it using a value from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` (or a [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191335/windows-equivalent-of-dev-random) [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049203/equivalent-of-dev-urandom-on-windows).